# If $f(x)=x^2$ why $f(x+1)=f(x)+2x+1$ instead of $f(x+1)=x^2+2x+1$?

Tags: calculus, functions

I'm reading Spivak's *Calculus*, there's a part where he suggests that the student should check some assertions:

$$f(x)=x^2$$

Then I've evaluated for $f(x+1)$ which is $f(x+1)=(x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1$. Why he says that $f(x+1)=f(x)+2x+1$? Does $f(x)=x^2$ in this case?

Comment: Because $f(x)=x^2$.

Comment: It is also $f(x+1)=f(x)+f^\prime(x)+1$. :)

Comment: @AndreaMori Why does $f'(x)=2x$?

Comment: @GustavoBandeira : if $f(x)=x^2$, what would $f^\prime(x)$ be?

Comment: Yes, but you created this premise now, it wasn't stated anywhere.

Comment: $f'(x)$ is the derivative of $f(x)$. If you know $f(x)=x^2$, then $f'(x)=2x$. This isn't an independent premise, it comes directly from what Clayton said.

Comment: @RobertMastragostino Now it's clear. I still don't know about derivatives. Invisible premises everywhere.

Comment: @GustavoBandeira : $f(x)=x^2$ is the starting point of your question ...

Comment: @Andrea Robert explained what I didn't know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $f(x)=x^2$,
$$f(x+1)=(x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1=f(x)+2x+1$$
Both are correct

Comment: Got it. But this notation left me a little confused.

Comment: @GustavoBandeira I see. Glad to help

Comment: @GustavoBandeira: I've not found out what is the problem trying to say. Of course, the answwer is complete.+1

Comment: @BabakSorouh My assumption is that it's testing the algebra needed to set up $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h$, and prepping the student to recognize the cancellation that will occur.